# How do make a nested table with a different border so that it doesn't inheritage from the main table

Tags: html, css, inheritance, nested-table

Now with this code I have a dashed and black border in both tables in main table and in nested table.
However, I want it to be a solid and white border for nested table and not to inherit a dashed and black border from the main table. Any clue how to do it?

```
<table class="outer-table";>
<tr><td colspan="2"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><table id="inner-table";>
                <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
                <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
                </table>
        </td><td rowspan="2"></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>

table.outer-table, td{ border: 5px dashed black;}
table.outer-table{ 
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color:red; 
    width:40%;
    height:60%;
 }

table#inner-table{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
background-color:yellow;
     border: 3px solid white; 
     width:90%;
     height:90%;
}
```

Comment: It's not inheriting from the main table, you are setting the table cell (td) border (for all tables) to dashed black. Table borders are different than Cell borders.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following CSS property to your `inner-table`'s, `td` element which will override the `#outer-table`'s `td` style:

```
table#inner-table td {
 border: 3px solid white;
}
```